# Проверка 1 списка на сходство по шаблону 2 списка и вывод результата

Tags: python, list, сравнение

Я хочу сравнить два списка: command и words. В command хранятся шаблоны слов, а в words - то, что введет сам пользователь. вот пример:

```
command = ['бег', 'прыжок', 'полет']
words = ['я', 'бегал', 'вчера']
```

мне нужно, чтобы программа написала, в данном случае, совпадение найдено, потому что бегал почти совпадает со словом бег из списка command. Сейчас я считаю, что это можно реализовать алгоритмом Вагнера — Фишера (чтобы каждой букве присваивался 1-сходство или 0-не сходство)
также может быть несколько слов или отпечатка (в слове есть лишняя буква, но так, чтобы смысл самого слова был понятен)
вот пример:

```
command = ['бег', 'прыжок', 'полет']
words = ['я', 'бегал', 'и', 'прыгал', 'вчера']
```

тут тоже программа видит, что некоторые слова из списка words практически совпадают со списком command, а значит программа напишет совпадение найдено

Comment: как получились 60%?

Comment: это как пример, то есть примерное значение. Не обязательно 60%, может и 80% или 77%. Эта программа сравнивает слова из words и смотрит, на сколько процентов они отличаются от шаблона command

Comment: Тогда приведите пример не как пример, а как точное значение. И как оно рассчитано. На сколько процентов схожи слова бег и бегать. Прыжок и прыгать. Пока что задача выглядит как "посчитайте мне что-то, только я сам не знаю, что именно".

Comment: Пример: 'бег' есть буквы 'б', 'e', 'г', 'бегать' есть буквы 'б', 'е', 'г', 'а', 'т', 'ь'. И там и там есть буквы 'б', 'e', 'г', однако в 1 слове нет 'а', 'т', 'ь'. Значит в слово бег отличается от слова бегать ровно на половину букв. В итоге получаем 50%. Затем проделываем тоже самое с остальными словами и получаем: прыгать отличается на 4 буквы от слова прыжок - значит 67%, а слово летать - на 50% от полет.

Comment: @Jeck22Jeck Так вам нужно сравнить отдельно каждое слово списка с соответствующим словом другого списка, и всё? Целиком списки не нужно сравнивать и слов в них всегда одинаковое кол-во?

Comment: в списке command - да, всегда одинаковое количество слов, однако в списке words не всегда одинаковое количество, поэтому и нужно сравнить слова из списка words с каждым словом из списка command (забыл добавить, что нужно каждое слово сравнить со всеми словами из списка command) в данной ситуации получится по 3 разных процентных соотношения на каждое слово (слово бегать - бег 50%, бегать-прыжок 0%, бегать - полет 40% и так с каждым словом из words)

Comment: Вы бы лучше описали - какая конечная цель этого? Вы пытаетесь определить, какие команды были даны пользователем, на что они наиболее похожи? Без контекста считать можно по-всякому и непонятен смысл этого всего.

Comment: Т.е. слова "крест" и "треск", а так же "шпала" и "лапша" и все остальные анаграммы одинаковы на 100%?

Comment: 'слова "крест" и "треск", а так же "шпала" и "лапша" одинаковы на 100%' Об этом я даже не подумал) К слову, я хотел сделать это через правило Левеншейна, но не знал, как лучше реализовать. Например, в списке command у меня больше 1000 слов, и мне надо сравнить, есть ли похожие слова в тексте, напечатанном пользователем. Для этого я разбиваю текст на слова (убираю верхний регистр и символы) и делаю из полученных слов список, затем сравниваю этот список слов с шаблоном command. В итоге по правилу Левеншейна нахожу похожие слова. Но точно, как это сделать, я не знаю.

Comment: Вот эта библиотека из моего ответа тоже использует Левенштейна, собственно )

Comment: Я попробую ваш пример использовать в моем коде, надеюсь, что все заработает. Если будут проблемы, я напишу

Comment: print(f'{fuzz.ratio(command, words)}%') - все работает, но мне нужно немного другое, а именно, чтобы эта программа находила сходство (просто писала не в процентах, а есть сходство или нет) тогда, когда хотя бы 1 слово или более из списка words, даже если слова немного отличались по написанию (но смысл слова не утрачивался) были почти схожи с 1 или несколькими словами из списка command. Правда, я не уверен, возможно ли эту идею вообще реализовать. Я буду очень благодарен, если вы сможете это сделать.

Comment: Поясните примерами, что вы хотите, и желательно прямо в самом вопросе

Comment: пришлось переформулировать вопрос полностью

Comment: Ну опять же вы чётко не сформулировали критерии. Мой ответ по-прежнему актуален - какой-то процент эта библиотека покажет и на этом примере, а как эти проценты трактовать, какой делать порог отсечения - это вы думайте.

Comment: я сделал пару экспериментов и немного сдвинулся с мертвой точки. Пока что я не могу сформулировать вопрос точно, т.к. сам не знаю, как осуществить мою идею.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вам "из коробки" практически ваш процент:

```
# pip install thefuzz[speedup]

from thefuzz import fuzz

command = ['бег', 'прыжок', 'полет']
words = ['бегать', 'прыгать', 'летать']
print(f'{fuzz.token_sort_ratio(command, words)}%')
```

Вывод:

```
59%
```

Но в любом случае, если вы не понимаете, что хотите считать, то это "сферические проценты в вакууме". Вот, например, другой процент с теми же данными:

```
print(f'{fuzz.ratio(command, words)}%')
```

Вывод:

```
74%
```

Если нужно просто сравнить соответствующие слова из двух списков, то так:

```
command = ['бег', 'прыжок', 'полет']
words = ['бегать', 'прыгать', 'летать']
for a, b in zip(command, words):
  print(f'{fuzz.ratio(a, b)}%')
```

Вывод:

```
67%
46%
55%
```